# Writing the correct value in the depth buffer when using ray-casting

Tags: opengl, shaders, depth-buffer

I am doing a ray-casting in a 3d texture until I hit a correct value. I am doing the ray-casting in a cube and the cube corners are already in world coordinates so I don't have to multiply the vertices with the `modelviewmatrix` to get the correct position.

**Vertex shader**

```
world_coordinate_ = gl_Vertex;
```

**Fragment shader**

```
vec3 direction = (world_coordinate_.xyz - cameraPosition_);
direction = normalize(direction);

for (float k = 0.0; k < steps; k += 1.0) {
....
pos += direction*delta_step;
float thisLum = texture3D(texture3_, pos).r;
if(thisLum > surface_)
...
}
```

Everything works as expected, what I now want is to sample the correct value to the depth buffer. The value that is now written to the depth buffer is the cube coordinate. But I want the value of `pos` in the 3d texture to be written.

So lets say the cube is placed `10` away from origin in `-z` and the size is `10*10*10`. My solution that does not work correctly is this:

```
pos *= 10;
pos.z += 10;
pos.z *= -1;

vec4 depth_vec = gl_ProjectionMatrix * vec4(pos.xyz, 1.0);
float depth = ((depth_vec.z / depth_vec.w) + 1.0) * 0.5; 
gl_FragDepth = depth;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

volumetric raycasting. I know something about that :).

But to you question:
When you have sample in world space (your `pos`) you have to multiply it with View*Projection matrix to have correct output of depth. View matrix contains linear basis of the camera and converts the world position to the camera space and then you do projection.

---

Using this depth with regular rendering pipeline is easy (if you are not able to write the depth into the depth buffer and use HW acceleration). Store world position in Vertex shader (using varying in gl i think). Than in PS perform viewProjection multiplication on this `worldPos`. Normalize (`pos /= pos.w`). And compare `pos.z` with the value in a depth texture. Thats it ;)

Comment: How do I get the view matrix in opengl:)? is the modelview matrix just after the gluLookAt has been used?

Comment: Well you have to split it. I don't know the exact correct function. But for just view matrix you can do. GlIdentity, GluLook at and thats the view matrix ;). Here is how to get the matrix: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8880/restoring-projection-matrix/8883#8883 but i was pointed that it is deprecated and i dont know how to do it correctly (because i'm directx guy), but i what i wrote should work ;]

Comment: nice, seems to work, no there is only one problem left, how to get the correct coordinates for the depth texture for the other objects

Comment: Other objects are volumetric too?

Comment: no they are normal object rendered in normal way

Comment: Ok, than it should be easy. You I'll edit the answer

Comment: I have the depth buffer in a uniform texture. But which coordinates should I use for the depth texture, Texturde2D(depth_texture, ?);
((pos.xy / w) + 1 * 0.5) ?

Comment: ((pos.xy / w) * 0.5 + 1) i think

Comment: Just for whoever gets to this question, it was answered by the author in this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451721/writing-the-correct-value-in-the-depth-buffer-when-using-ray-casting/6622709#6622709